# How do you include an erlang app in a release, but have rebar not start it?

Tags: erlang, rebar

I'm using rebar to compile & generate a release.

Under my /apps folder, i have app1, app2. Currently the rel/reltool.config had app1, app2 configured. The console works as expected without errors.

I want only app1 to start on node startup, and manually start app2 via app1's supervisor.

Various Attempts at commenting/different values of incl_cond, etc have led to rebar generate errors like "must include app2 in release, cannot be excluded"

Suggestions appreciated.
~B

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either make `app2` an [included application](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/included_applications.html) of `app1`, by adding this to `app1.app.src`:

```
{included_applications, [app2]}
```

Or in your `reltool.config`, mark app2 as load-only, like this:

```
{rel, "myrelease", "1",
   [
     kernel,
     stdlib,
     sasl,
     app1,
     {app2, load}
   ]},
```

Comment: Thanks legoscia ( and rnewson on #rebar irc ) for the solution.

Comment: However, applications in app2.app Resource file would be started, is there anyway else ?